# Nginx NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

Tags: ssl, nginx, digital-ocean

I'm trying to enable ssl certificates for my web app deployed on `DigitalOcean` but when I'm accessing the droplet ip I'm getting this error:

> NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
>   This server could not prove that it is droplet-ip-address; its security certificate is from *.domain.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

This is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
        # SSL configuration
        #
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name sub.domain.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/star-op/__company_com.ca-chain.cert.pem
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/star-op/__company_com.key;
}
```

At this moment I don't have any DNS record from `sub.domain.com` that points to my ip address... can this be the cause of that error?

Comment: Are you accessing the droplet via its IP access?

Comment: @ShawnC. yes, that's how I access the droplet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without a DNS entry, you are doing something like `https://x.x.x.x` which `nginx` associating with `https://sub.domain.com` most likely as it is the only server block in `nginx` at this time.

But `https://x.x.x.x` does not match the cert for `https://sub.domain.com` so your are getting a mismatch. If you are just testing you could add a `host` file entry for testing which should get you past this issue. Afterward, you would need to add a DNS entry to your public DNS server for the rest of the world to not have this issue.

Comment: Is this the correct way to add a `host` file entry? 
`x.x.x.x:80 sub.domain.com`

Comment: host file doesn't deal with ports so just x.x.x.x domain